# update list of dictionaries with values from another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Given two list of dictionaries:

```
students = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "A"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "B"},
    {"id": 99, "name": "C"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "D"},
    {"id": 101, "name": "E"},
]

classes = [
    {"id": 1, "students": [1, 99]},
    {"id": 2, "students": [1, 99, 101, 4]},
    {"id": 3, "students": [4, 101]},
]
```

The `classes` list has dictionaries with a `students` key, the values of this key is also a list for example `[1, 99]` for the first dict `{"id": 1, "students": [1, 99]}` of `classes`. I would like to replace these numbers `[1,99]` with the dictionary from `students` whenever the `id` key in `students` match with the integer present in the key `students`.

For example, the first result would be :  `{"id": 1, "students": [{"id": 1, "name": "A"}, {"id": 99, "name": "C"}]}`.

Here is my attempt but I'm not getting it right:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (students, classes):
    for elem in l:
        d[elem['id']].update(elem)
l3 = d.values()
print(l3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping `id` -> student dict. This way we can map `id`s present in `classes['student']` to corresponding student dict.

```
id_to_student = {dct["id"]: dct for dct in students}
# {1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'A'},
#  2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'B'},
#  99: {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'},
#  4: {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'},
#  101: {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'}}

# Now update `classes` dict
for dct in classes:
    dct['students'] = [id_to_student[idx] for idx in dct['students']]

# [{'id': 1, 'students': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'}]},
#  {'id': 2, 'students': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'}, {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}]}, 
#  {'id': 3, 'students': [{'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}, {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created an empty list `new_classes` to store the results in. Then I have iterated through each dict in the `classes` list. For each dict, I get the list in students using `ids = dic['students']`, then I use list comprehension to go thorugh each dict in students and check if the id matches one of the ids in the list, and if so keep it (`[i for i in students if i['id'] in ids]`) and replace the 'students' vale in that dict with the result. Then I append the whole updated dict to the new list. Full code:

```
new_classes = []
for dic in classes:
    ids = dic['students']
    dic['students'] = [i for i in students if i['id'] in ids]
    new_classes.append(dic)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'students': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'}]},
 {'id': 2,
  'students': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'},
   {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'},
   {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'},
   {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'}]},
 {'id': 3, 'students': [{'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}, {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'}]}]
```

Comment: Your answer is good, however on the 2nd "class" the order of the students gets swapped from `[1, 99, 101, 4]` to `[1, 99, 4, 101]`. This may be an issue, depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
from copy import deepcopy
from pprint import pprint

students = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "A"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "B"},
    {"id": 99, "name": "C"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "D"},
    {"id": 101, "name": "E"},
]

classes = [
    {"id": 1, "students": [1, 99]},
    {"id": 2, "students": [1, 99, 101, 4]},
    {"id": 3, "students": [4, 101]},
]

_classes = deepcopy(classes)
for idx, classe in enumerate(classes):
    _classes[idx]['students'] = []
    for i in classe['students']:
        student = [x for x in students if x.get('id') == i]
        _classes[idx]['students'].append(student[0])
classes = _classes
pprint(classes)
```

Result

```
[{'id': 1, 'students': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'}, {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'}]},
 {'id': 2,
  'students': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A'},
               {'id': 99, 'name': 'C'},
               {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'},
               {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}]},
 {'id': 3, 'students': [{'id': 4, 'name': 'D'}, {'id': 101, 'name': 'E'}]}]
```